# How to prevent duplicates in mongodb time series collection

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, time-series

### Problem

Sensors check-in periodically, but network connectivity issues may cause them to check-in with the same data more than once.

MongoDB does not allow the `unique` property on secondary indexes for time series collections (MongoDB 5.0). [Timeseries Limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/)

In addition, calculations need to be done on the data (preferably using aggregations) that involve counting the number of entries, which will be inaccurate if there are duplicates. Not to mention it bloats the database and is just messy.

### Question

Is there any way to prevent duplicate entries in a MongoDB Timeseries collection?

Comment: How are the data inserted into the DB? If they are inserted through some API, you might consider doing some checking/dedupe at the API level.

Comment: They are, but that is not efficient, so I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I'm stuck at this right now too, the best thing I've thought of is to do a count query using the unique properties on my records, if the count returns 1 then the record I am trying to insert is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.

According to official answer in MongoDB Community, there is no way to ensure unique values in timeseries collection.

You can check the full explanations here:
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/duplicate-data-issue/135023

They consider it a caveat of timeseries compare to normal collection. IMO, it's a crucial lack in the timeseries capability of mongodb...

There is currently two available solutions:

1. Use "normal" collection with a compound unique index on your timestamp and sensor_id fields
2. Keep using timeseries collection, but query your data only through aggregation pipeline with a `$group` stage to eliminate duplicate entries